# How do I add an icon to my Xcode project?

Tags: xcode, macos, icons

I have an Xcode project for Mac OSX, and I'd like to add an icon file (.icns) to my project and set it as the App Icon. How would I do this?

Comment: Your question is confusing. The default Dock icon is the main app icon. I have no idea what a BarIcon is. Are you trying to change your application icon, or to add other kinds of icons (e.g., for menu items, Menu Bar Extras, toolbar controls, sidebar sources, or buttons), or something else?

Comment: Also, have you looked at the [Human Interface Guidelines](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/userexperience/Conceptual/AppleHIGuidelines/Intro/Intro.html) and [High Resolution Guidelines](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/GraphicsAnimation/Conceptual/HighResolutionOSX/Introduction/Introduction.html)? If not, look at their sections on icons, and, if they don't answer you, they should at least help you ask a more specific and answerable question here.

Comment: No No! is much simpler than that! I just want my app icon has only!

Answer (score 13):

The key here is that you need an ICNS (icon set) file.

The right way to create this is described in the [Human Interface Guidelines](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/userexperience/Conceptual/AppleHIGuidelines/Intro/Intro.html), and the details are covered in various user's guides and reference guides in Apple's maze of twisty little documentation, but I'll summarize it here.

There are third-party tools that can do this, as well as plugins for Photoshop, GIMP, Illustrator, etc., that can output a correct .icns file. But make sure, if you use such a thing, it's up to date, because Apple changes the rules all the time.

If you need to do it manually, here's what you do:

First, create a set of PNG files at different sizes. The exact list of what you need changes over time. See [Provide the Correct Resources and Let OS X Do the Work](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/userexperience/Conceptual/AppleHIGuidelines/IconsImages/IconsImages.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000967-TP6) if that link lasts longer than the current list; otherwise, search for it at http://developer.apple.com yourself. But, as of early 2013, it's 512x512, 256x256, 128x128, 32x32, 16x16, and @2x versions of each. All of them should have the sRGB color profile embedded in them. They should be named either `icon_512x512@2x.png`, `icon_512x512.png`, etc., or `MyApp_512x512@2x.png`, `MyApp_512x512.png`, etc. Put them all in a directory together named, e.g., `MyApp.iconset`.

"But wait! I just want an icon, I don't want all those sizes!" Well, you really *do* want all those sizes. Your 512x512 icon will look horrible when scaled down to 32x32. And on a Retina Mac, when your icon gets scaled up to double resolution, instead of getting sharper it'll just get jagged. Also, if you want to get into the App Store, Apple will reject you if you don't have them. But, if you insist, you can get away with just putting `icon-512x512.png` in the folder, and follow the rest of the steps, and it will work.

From the Terminal, cd into the parent directory, and type `iconutil -c icns MyApp.iconset`. You will get a file called `MyApp.icns`.

Now you can do the steps suggested by Douglas, and it will actually work. In Xcode, select your project in the Project Navigator, select your app target in the project sidebar, select the Summary tab, and drag `MyApp.icns` from Finder to the App Icon box.

This may not have any visible effect in the GUI, except to add `MyApp.icns` to the Project Navigator. In other words, you may still see the "?" icon. This seems to be a bug in Xcode 4.5. If you follow the out-of-date recommendations from the HIG two versions ago, Xcode always shows the icon, but if you follow the current HIG, it doesn't. Go figure. Hopefully Apple will fix that some day.

But for now, it doesn't matter. Build the project, and then look at `MyApp.app`, and it will have your icon in the Finder, on the Dock, etc.

Now, I know you don't want to draw the same picture in 10 different variations, you just want something simple. As long as you don't want to get into the App Store, you can get away with cheating, in two ways:

- Scale the 512x512 (1024x1024 pixel "512x512@2x" if supporting hi res) image to all of the other sizes, using your favorite tool.
- Create a .icns with nothing but the 512x512 image in the iconset.

The second one is simpler, and less cheat-y, and ultimately Finder is probably going to scale your 512x512 image as well as you would have anyway.

Finally, if you've manually edited your `Info.plist` or changed build settings (or you're using a project imported from a much easier version of Xcode), just dragging the image may not be enough. If you need to do the same steps manually, here they are:

- `MyApp.icns` has to be in the Project Navigator as a file in your project. (You can drag it here from Finder.)
- In Build Phases, the Copy Bundle Resources should include `MyApp.icns`. (You can drag it here from the Project Navigator.) (If you're not using the normal Build Phases for some reason, you need some other way to get it copied to `Contents/Resources/MyApp.icns` at build time.)
- Your Info.plist should have an `Icon file` (raw name `CFBundleIconFile`) named `MyApp`, with no extension.

That's all there is to it.

Comment: Workinnnnnngggggg!!!! sucessful!!! thanks thanks thank All right!!!But really worked when I replace "-" with "_" but what matters friend that worked! thank you

Comment: icon-512x512.png > icon_512x512.png

Comment: @JosiasViskoo: It ought to work with either one, or even nothing; last time I checked, `iconutil` was just looking for ending with "512x512", not "_512x512"… but the HIG does definitely use underscores, so +1 for pointing it out, and I'll edit the answer.

Comment: Glad to see it all worked out.  Good luck on future projects.

Comment: @JosiasViskoo, Don't forget to accept abarnert's answer by checking on the check mark near the top!!

Comment: Would the 256x256@2x be the same as the 512x512 image?

Comment: Thanks a lot, your second way save for me a lot of time!

Answer (score 0):

1. In the project navigator, select an asset catalog.
2. Choose Editor > Add Assets > App Icons & Launch Images > New OS X Icon.
3. An empty OS X icon set is created, with an image well for each image representation in the set.
4. Drag icon file from the Finder to the appropriate image well in the set viewer.

Alternatively, you can add images by selecting an asset catalog, and choosing Editor > Add Assets > Import.

Answer (score -2):

I am pretty sure you will have to put your icons into the project and then recompile.  Let us know how it goes.

Comment: But, eu select a icon 512px x 512px and the logo icon not show... :/

Comment: You have to make sure you connect the icon in your plist.

Comment: No No! is much simpler than that! I just want my app icon has only!

Comment: Are you just trying to give your app an icon so it shows up on the desktop?

Comment: yesss! Just it! Just apply a PNG icon, replace the icon default

Comment: Ok, if you have the PNG icon, drag it onto the project outline to the left of your window.  Xcode will ask if you want to "copy item into destination group's folder"  Say yes by checking the box next to Destination on the pop up window.  This will put your icon in your project.  Then, click on the name of your project in the left hand side all the way at the top.  Make sure you click on Targets, your app name and click on summary in the middle window.  You should see a spot for app icons.  Drag your PNG file here at it will hook up everything for you.  Good luck, hope it works out.

Comment: But there is have a "?" then do not show my icon... Just a "?"

Comment: @Douglas: I'm pretty sure you can't just drop a PNG there, you need an ICNS. Otherwise, it will appear to work, but you'll end up with an Info.plist that refers to "my_icon" rather than "my_icon.png", which will make Finder/Dock/etc. look for "my_icon.icns", which means they'll find nothing and display a default icon.